# Hibernate native query shows exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have written hibernate native query for getting total users and month from table.
But it shows :

```
exception:Operand should contain 1 column(s)
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
```

could anyone please help me for solving this:

```
  c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
     .add(Projections.sqlProjection("(select count(*), MONTH(Stored) from adbtbl_stat " 
     + "where Activity = 89 and YEAR(Stored) = 2015) as Count, month",
     new String[] { "Count", "month" }, new Type[] { LongType.INSTANCE, StringType.INSTANCE }))
     .add(Projections.groupProperty(month(stored))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [ProjectionList](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/ProjectionList.html) can contain multiple [SQLProjection(s)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/SQLProjection.html), but each SQLProjection should be associated to one and only one SQL columns.

You SQLProjection tries to select two columns instead.

Try replacing your Criteria query with a simple native query instead:

```
Long activity = ...;
int year = ...;

Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "select count(*) as Count, MONTH(Stored) as Month " +
    "from adbtbl_stat " +
    "where Activity = :activity and YEAR(Stored) = :year"
);
q.setParameter("activity", activity);
q.setParameter("year", year);
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();
```